# Time period within which we are required to travel after getting the visa

Tags: visas, pakistani-citizens, residency, portugal

I am a Pakistani national working in Portugal. My wife was issued a Portuguese resident visa valid for 120 days on 10th June 2017. Due to some unfortunate circumstances she is still not able to travel to Portugal, her visa will expire in the first week of October 2017.

Some friends told me that it is necessary to travel within one month after getting the visa. I want to know that is there some kind of restriction like this? And will there be any issue if she decides to travel to Portugal now. 
(The visa is a Type D Schengen visa).

Comment: How would such a restriction make sense? Ignore those friends

Answer (score 1):

[The website](http://www.secomunidades.pt/vistos/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=112:vistos-de-residencia&catid=42&Itemid=96&lang=en) of visa portal of Ministry of Foreign Affairs of Portugal doesn't mention any such restriction about traveling within one month after getting the residence visa.

Note that ([Source](http://www.secomunidades.pt/vistos/)):

> A residence visa is usually valid for 2 entries and 4 months, after
>   which its holder must have obtained a residence permit.

So, make sure that your wife has some time to apply for residence permit once she's in Portugal before her residence visa expires.

Comment: Not 100% certain about Schengen residence visas, but normally visa validity dates indicate the period of time during which you can reach the border and request admission.  The 4 month permitted stay starts the day you enter and expires after four months irregardless of the date of expiration of the visa.  One would think she has to apply for her resident permit before the 4 month stay expires not before the visa expires.

Comment: No, temporary Schengen residence visas don't start the day you enter, but the day you obtain a visa. At least that was the case with my temporary German Schengen visa before I got the residence permit.